# Creating Python package with new name keeping old package import intact

Tags: python, import, pypi

Not sure if I have got the title correct but here short description on the issue. I have a package `A` on GitHub and PyPI and its usage is:

```
pip install A
import A 
A.module()
```

Current directory structure:

- `A`

  - `__init__.py`

I would like to create a new package `B` on PyPI but would like keep backward compatibility so below works:

```
pip install B
import A 
A.module()

import B
B.module()
```

just so existing applications don’t break want to ensure `import A` works.

What are the possible solutions to achieve this?

Comment: This is problematic, what should be the behavior if somebody has pip installed A and B? Should import A import it from A or from B?

Comment: Ok I could avoid having to support import B..primary goal is to ensure import A still works.

Comment: Re-read your comment and forgot to add that I don't intend to continue supporting pip install A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution name (what goes after "pip install") and the package import name(s) are entirely independent. It is only a common convention for the install name to match the import name.

So just do like this in your installer:

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="B",
    version="0.1",
    packages=["A", "B"],
    ...
)
```

In the setup call, the "name" keyword argument is the distribution name that users would use to install the package - `python -m pip install B` in this case. The generated artifacts which you upload to PyPI would have this `B` in the filename, e.g.

```
B-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
B-0.1.tar.gz
```

The `packages` keyword argument are the top-level import names, of which there can be multiple, and these would usually match your project directory structure:

```
.
├── A
│   └── __init__.py
├── B
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

This allows the "B" distribution to provide both A and B imports, and act as a drop-in replacement for the "A" distribution.

Comment: Thanks @wim, will try this out and update how it goes.